# capture screen in active panel from window opened from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I created a page-event google-chrome-extension that creates a new window when pressing a button on the extension's popup. I wan't to take screenshots from the active panel by pressing a button in the new window. I do that by sending a message to a background page to do the capture there, but I always get this error:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabCapture.capture:
>   Extension has not been invoked for the current page (see activeTab
>   permission). Chrome pages cannot be captured

If I understand correctly, that capture should be initiated by a user action either in the extension popup or in the active panel directly. there is some way to setup things so the click in the extension content page be accepted as generated in the current page?

----manifest------

```
"background" : {
    "page": "background.html",
    "persistent": false
  },
  "page_action" :{
    "default_popup": "popup.html" },
  "permissions": ["activeTab",  "declarativeContent",  "tabCapture",  "background"],
```

-----------background.js--------

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.command === "init_capture"){
      locate_tab(function(){
        init_capture();
      });

function init_capture(e){

    video = document.querySelector('video');
      canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      var MediaStreamConstraint = {
            //audio: true,
            video: true,
            videoConstraints: {
                mandatory: {
                    chromeMediaSource: 'tab',
                    minWidth: 640,
                    maxWidth: 800,
                    minHeight: 420,
                    maxHeight: 600
                }
            }
      };

           chrome.tabCapture.capture(MediaStreamConstraint, function(stream){ 
console.log(stream); //always null.. activeTab error
});
    }
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well.. I got to a simple solution, I would like to share this with the hope that other users share different approach to this problem:

1. in my case, I have a "launch window" button in my popup, and a "init capture" and "capture frame" buttons in the new window. 
   So, instead of messing around with permissions, I removed the "init capture" button from the new window, and put that code in the same handler for the popup "launch window" button, bypassing in this way the security restrictions.
2. I keep a hidden canvas and video tags in the background page, and that is where the real capturing happens. when the user press "capture frame" on new window, it just send a message to the background page that returns via callback the content of the canvas.